# How to use namespace and use in PHP?

Tags: php

I have file `index.php` in directory `Main`;

There are also directory `Helpers` inside `Main` with class `Helper`.

I tried to inject class `Helpers\Helper` in `index.php` as:

```
<?

namespace Program;

use Helpers\Helper;


class Index {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $class = new Helper();
    }

}
```

But it does not work.

How to use namespace and use in PHP?

Comment: _But it does not work._ How exactly?

Comment: Phpstorms highlights as red this `use`

Comment: Undefined namespace `Helpers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With Your Description, Your Directory Structure should look something similar to this:

```
    Main*
        -- Index.php
        |
        Helpers*
               --Helper.php
```

> If You are **going by the book with regards to PSR-4 Standards**, Your Class definitions could look similar to the ones shown below:

**Index.php**

```
    <?php
        // FILE-NAME: Index.php.
        // LOCATED INSIDE THE "Main" DIRECTORY
        // WHICH IS PRESUMED TO BE AT THE ROOT OF YOUR APP. DIRECTORY

        namespace Main;            //<== NOTICE Main HERE AS THE NAMESPACE...

        use Main\Helpers\Helper;   //<== IMPORT THE Helper CLASS FOR USE HERE   

        // IF YOU ARE NOT USING ANY AUTO-LOADING MECHANISM, YOU MAY HAVE TO 
        // MANUALLY IMPORT THE "Helper" CLASS USING EITHER include OR require
        require_once __DIR__ . "/helpers/Helper.php";

        class Index {

            public function __construct(){
                $class = new Helper();
            }

        }
```

**Helper.php**

```
    <?php
        // FILE NAME Helper.php.
        // LOCATED INSIDE THE "Main/Helpers" DIRECTORY


        namespace Main\Helpers;     //<== NOTICE Main\Helpers HERE AS THE NAMESPACE...


        class Helper {

            public function __construct(){
                // SOME INITIALISATION CODE
            }

        }
```

Comment: I still get error: `Class 'Main\Helpers\Helper' not found in` in `index.php`

Comment: May be I should use `include()` above before namespace?

Comment: @MisterPi You have to find a Way to either autoload the class or simply require it manually using either require or include.... the Post was updated to reflect that....

Comment: @MisterPi  Just at: `require_once __DIR__ . "/helpers/Helper.php";` at the top of your `Index.php` File.... just after the namespace declaration....

Comment: For what then I need to use `use` if I do `require_once` anyway?

Comment: @MisterPi  Because the Concept of `Namespace` in PHP does not imply automatic Class-Loading. `Namespace` in PHP is similar to `Package` in Java. Why Namespaces? Code-Organization, Modularity and protection from Naming Conflicts. Assuming you have another Class that you cloned from Git that is also called `Helper`.  Now, assume that you need both Classes inside `Index.php` but your entire Codebase doesn't use any Namespacing. Now, How would PHP know the exact `Helper` Class to use? The One you wrote or the One from an external Source? Anyways; whether you use namespace or not you need to import

Comment: @MisterPi Anyways; whether you use namespace or not, you'd still need to Load the Class-Files. This is where Autoloaders or Class Loaders come in to do their Jobs. So *at this Point, you are looking for an Autoloader or ClassLoader* which will ***still do the require or include but behind the scenes and only when the Class in Question is requested.*** But then; if you are not using an Autoloader; you still have to do that manually because **NAMESPACE !== AUTOLOADER** They are 2 totally  different Concepts. **;-)**